# How do I display an item which is in the list multiple times?

Tags: python

It always gives me the first time it appears with `.index()`. I want index to equal the places of the list. For example, `This word appears in the places, 0,4`. If the user typed chicken that would be the output.

```
dlist = ["chicken","potato","python","hammer","chicken","potato","hammer","hammer","potato"]
x=None
while x != "":
    print ("\nPush enter to exit")
    x = input("\nGive me a word from this list: Chicken, Potato, Python, or Hammer")
    y = x.lower()
    if y in dlist:
        count = dlist.count(y)
        index = dlist.index(y)
        print ("\nThis word appears",count,"times.")
        print ("\nThis word appears in the places",index)
    elif y=="":
        print ("\nGood Bye")
    else:
        print ("\nInvalid Word or Number")
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Can you post your expected output, and your current output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
r = [i for i, w in enumerate(dlist) if w == y]
print ("\nThis word appears",len(r),"times.")
print ("\nThis word appears in the places", r)
```

instead of

```
count = dlist.count(y)
index = dlist.index(y)
print ("\nThis word appears",count,"times.")
print ("\nThis word appears in the places",index)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
all_indexes = [idx for idx, value in enumerate(dlist) if value == y]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work:

```
index_list = [i for i in xrange(len(dlist)) if dlist[i] == "hammer"]
```

That gives the list `[3, 6, 7]` in your example...

Comment: Any time you're using `xrange(len())` you should probably be using `enumerate`.